# Indenting two spaces a selection (visual mode) in vim?

Tags: vim, editor, indentation

Say I have this code:

```
var users = [
  { name: 'TJ', email: 'tj@earnboost.com' },
  { name: 'Loki', email: 'loki@earnboost.com' },
  { name: 'Jane', email: 'jane@earnboost.com' }
  ];
```

I want to select the three lines inside the variable (in visual mode) and indent it two spaces:

```
var users = [
    { name: 'TJ', email: 'tj@earnboost.com' },
    { name: 'Loki', email: 'loki@earnboost.com' },
    { name: 'Jane', email: 'jane@earnboost.com' }
  ];
```

How can I accomplish that in vim?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Provided your `sw` is two, you can do visually select three lines (`V`) and do a `>`. You can also select column of one space and three lines (ctrl-v), hit `s` and replace the said space with three spaces, then hit esc and all three lines will benefit from this improvements. And there are more ways I'm sure. Normally, you'd do the `>` and have your `sw` set to whatever indentation you want in your code.

Comment: in visual mode, you need a single `>`. Also, in block visual capital `A` and `I` are better than `s` or `c` if you need to append/insert and not replace.

Comment: Correct on both accounts. The first one, I fixed, the second left as is, because what I've written is not *wrong* :) But thanks.

Comment: Try also `%vi[k>` Normal mode command (assuming that the cursor is on the `var users`-line).

Comment: ib, that would sure do, but this is, basically a macro to record ;-)

Comment: I had to use `set sw=2` first to get the two spaces, in case anyone didn't know how to set the space width :)

Answer (score 10):

after you select lines in visual mode. enter ":", the "'<,'>"  will auto added, then enter norm I and two space(space key).

```
:'<,'>norm I<space><space>
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed.  It bumps every line to the right X number of spaces.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Youre friend here are `:le` and `:ri`:

> ```
> :[range]ri[ght] [width]                                 :ri :right  
>
>      Right-align lines in [range] at [width] columns
>      (default 'textwidth' or 80 when 'textwidth' is 0). 
>      {not in Vi}
>
> :[range]le[ft] [indent]                                 :le :left     
>
>        Left-align lines in [range].  Sets the indent in the        
>        lines to [indent] (default 0).  {not in Vi}
> ```

Thus just visually select your lines, and then execute one of the aboves like:

```
:'<,'>ri 2
```

or

```
:'<,'>le 5
```

(Note: the `'<,'>` part is automatically created by VIM, it's the content that you have visually selected)

Comment: The numbers 2 and 5 are just examples btw. You need to change them :)

Comment: That is not indenting. It will mess up existing levels of indentation in the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

For indenting a block between `{` and `}` (or between `()`, `[]`) the way it should be indented, I use `=%` with the cursor on the first `{` (resp. `(`, `[`).

For indenting 3 lines to the right, I use `3>>` with the cursor on the first line.